Can we increase code distance for stabilizer codes by fixing logical operators?
Assume we have a $[[n, k, d]]$ stabilizer code and each of its logical qubit has the same weight $d$. Can we generate a new code $[[n,k',d']]$ with $k'<k$ and $d'>d$ by fixing some logical operators $\bar{X}_i$ or $\bar{Z}_i$ as the stabilizer generators for the new codes? If so, what's the condition for choosing the right logical operators to fix?

This is kind of what's happening in subsystem codes. If you measure just the stabilizers of subsystem codes, you get a bunch of short-distance logical operators (the gauge operators). But if you "gauge fix" by measuring some subset of the gauge operators, you get a code with large distance.

It is certainly possible in principle, although I don't know of a consistent way of doing it. It's perhaps easier to see going in the opposite direction - start with an $[[n,k',d']]$ code and remove some stabilizers. $k$ obviously goes up, and the distance will typically drop. The toric code is probably a good example. Remove 3 of the stabilizers of the same type and you effectively create 2 holes (the first removal does nothing because it was linearly dependent upon all the others). A string of errors between those two holes will be a logical operator, so you can massively cut the distance depending on where you place them.

Thanks! Do you think that we should always fix the minimal weight logical operator, for example, chosen from ${\prod X_{i1}X_{i2}....X_{ij}}$? In your example, it seems like the short string between two defects are the minimal weight one and should be fixed.

That would certainly seem an obvious starting point in order to increase the distance. Of course, that assumes that there's only a small number of those, rather than many all of the same weight.
